# Caption nobreakspace error

Tags: captions

Latex gives an error "Command \nobreakspace is unavailable in encoding T1" for the \caption{Beam3}. When I delete the caption the error disappears. I am not using \nobreakspace command explicitly anywhere. How did this happen and what can I do to fix it?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.06]{beam3.jpg}
\caption{Beam3}
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: additionally there are no "hidden" unicode chars in this example, so as DG' says, please provide a full minimal example, the issue is likely to be somewhere else in your document.